# Documenting C# Properties with Breathe

Tags: c#, properties, doxygen, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am using Doxygen, Breathe and Sphinx to create some documentation that I want to put on Read the Docs regarding a simple C# library. Initially, my `make.bat` script was giving me lots of errors, which I realized were due to the use of fully-qualified names in Doxygen; I fixed this problem by way of the Doxygen `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES` option.

Unfortunately, my **properties** still aren't documenting properly. For one thing, unlike the documentation that is generated for my methods, the name of the property is still fully-qualified (i.e. `NAMESPACE::CLASS::PROPERTY`). Furthermore, the generated Read the Doc documentation does not contain **the data type** of the property and it's not properly picking up the comment tags. My C# code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the property.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The property.
/// </value>
public int Property { get; set; }
```

But the generated documentation looks like this:

> property NAMESPACE::CLASS::Property
>
> Gets or sets the property.
>
> The property.

I want to see something like this:

> property int Property
>
> Summary: Gets or sets the property.
>
> Value: The property.

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect?

The `make.bat` script continues to give me errors for these properties as well.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES` option!

Comment: Did you every get this to work?

Comment: I do not believe that I did.